# R alternative to full_join, right_join, merge without increasing rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, data-wrangling

Consider 2 dfs:

df1:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 |
| Bob | Sweets | 0.1 |
| Abe | Sweets | 0.1 |

df2:

| Col A | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Cola | 0.3 |

If I use `full_join`, `right_join`, or `merge` with `by = "Col A"` (with `all.y=TRUE`), I get each "permutation" as its own row:

df3:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Bob | Sweets | 0.1 | N/A | N/A |
| Abe | Sweets | 0.1 | N/A | N/A |

If I use `inner_join`, `left_join`, or `merge` with `by = "Col A"` (without `all.y=TRUE`), I get the same as above except subsetted to only the rows manipulated, for example, rows with Abe and Bob would be removed:

df4:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Cola | 0.3 |

I'm trying to do a merge without increasing the number of rows, because the unique permutations don't matter. It doesn't matter what order they get joined, either. Intended output:

df5:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Ice Cream | 0.2 | Sweets | 0.5 |
| Tom | Candy | 0.4 | Chocolate | 0.2 |
| Tom | Lollipop | 0.6 | Cola | 0.3 |
| Bob | Sweets | 0.1 | N/A | N/A |
| Abe | Sweets | 0.1 | N/A | N/A |

Filtering df3 by `unique` doesn't help because the permutations are indeed unique.

In my scenario, I am 100% sure that every subsequent df to join to df1 has exactly 3 rows, which matches with the original number of rows with "Tom" present in `df1$'Col A'`.

In my real scenario, this join/merge would be deployed in a loop, where each entry in `Col A` has exactly 3 occurrences as well. So in later loops, it will do the same for "Abe" and "Bob".

`bind_cols()` isn't versatile enough because the columns may have already been created in a previous loop (i.e. `Col D` and `Col E` would be already created by Tom's loop, with `N/A`s for Abe and Bob's rows). In this scenario, I only want the values to be imputed, not create new columns (which would further conflict by having the same colnames).

Is there a script/function/package to do what I'm intending? Converting to tibbles is fine as well. Maybe a some conditions to combine a `_join`/`merge` with a `bind_cols`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `*_join` does not know which row to join with, so it joins to all three. Given your expected output, you would like the `Tom` rows to join in the same order that they appear in the dataframes. You can add a `rowid` column, which will let `*_join` know that you want to join `Tom/1` to `Tom/1`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ColA    ColB    ColC
Tom IceCream    0.2
Tom Candy   0.4
Tom Lollipop    0.6
Bob Sweets  0.1
Abe Sweets  0.1", h = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
ColA    ColD    ColE
Tom Sweets  0.5
Tom Chocolate   0.2
Tom Cola    0.3", h = T)



# add row ids
df1 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ColA) %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number())

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number())


# join
left_join(df1,df2)
#> Joining, by = c("ColA", "rowid")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   ColA [3]
#>   ColA  ColB      ColC rowid ColD       ColE
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <int> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 Tom   IceCream   0.2     1 Sweets      0.5
#> 2 Tom   Candy      0.4     2 Chocolate   0.2
#> 3 Tom   Lollipop   0.6     3 Cola        0.3
#> 4 Bob   Sweets     0.1     1 <NA>       NA  
#> 5 Abe   Sweets     0.1     1 <NA>       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

An alternative to assigning `rowid`s would be to subset `df1` based on `ColA`, run `cbind`/`bind_cols`, then rejoin with `df1`.

```
df1 %>%
  filter(ColA == unique(df2$ColA)) %>%
  bind_cols(df2[,-1]) %>%
  right_join(df1)

#-----------
Joining, by = c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC")
  ColA     ColB ColC      ColD ColE
1  Tom IceCream  0.2    Sweets  0.5
2  Tom    Candy  0.4 Chocolate  0.2
3  Tom Lollipop  0.6      Cola  0.3
4  Bob   Sweets  0.1      <NA>   NA
5  Abe   Sweets  0.1      <NA>   NA
```